# Mocking raw POST data

Tags: php, http, post

I am writing PHPUnit test cases for a web application. As the tests are run within a command line environment, I am mocking a number of predefined variables such as **$_POST**, **$_GET**,**$_SERVER**, etc.. My test has to make sure that my controller class parses properly JSON input  (which is sent as raw POST and red through **php://input**). The question is, how can I manipulate the value of php://input without running a web server?

Answer (score 2):

POST data is whatever is fed to PHP's stdin, subject to the CONTENT_LENGTH environment variable telling PHP how many bytes to read (so to change the post data, you simply pipe in something different)

GET data is whatever is in the QUERY_STRING environment variable.

See [this](http://hoohoo.ncsa.illinois.edu/cgi/env.html) for other environment variables that can be useful to set that are used by PHP to populate things like $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have not separated concerns enough ; the way I see it, you should have :

- one method that gets raw data from php://input and passes that data to another method
- the second method that receives a string, and parses it as JSON

Each one of those two methods is responsible of one and only one thing ; this way, you can **unit**-test.

In your case, you can unit-test the behavior of the second method (the one that actually does the work) -- without depending on where the input comes from.

Answer (score 0):

What about moving the reading functionality to a class (or even a closure if you're on PHP 5.3), then just replacing it with a mock instance when testing?